# dask csv reading order

Tags: python, csv, dask

I have a time series which values are stored in different csv. 
Each csv is sorted and contains a variable seconds that is a time scan.

```
    df = dd.read_csv('/home/data/derived/ips_subnets.7days/*')
df.head()

          seconds                IP        subnet
    0  1477252800  Private-10.0.0.0   10.101.15.6
    1  1477252800  Private-10.0.0.0  10.102.223.2
    2  1477252800  Private-10.0.0.0  10.104.15.43
    3  1477252800  Private-10.0.0.0  10.104.5.241
    4  1477252800  Private-10.0.0.0  10.106.15.26
```

Now how can I set that the  csv files should be read in order according to the variable `seconds`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `dask.dataframe.read_csv` reads files in alphabetical order, so if your filenames follow a standard naming scheme, like `2016-05-06.csv` then you should be OK.

If you want, you can customize this with [dask.delayed](http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/delayed-collections.html).  Here is a similar [example notebook](https://gist.github.com/mrocklin/e7b7b3a65f2835cda813096332ec73ca).

Finally you can always call `df = df.set_index('seconds')`, however this is much slower than the alternatives and requires a full scan of the data.